# drupal #default_value not working for #type radios

Tags: forms

i am editing a form in drupal **7.1** and want to add a group of radios

```
    $form['yearofstudy']= array(
   '#title'=>'What is your year of study',
   '#type' => 'radios',
   '#options' => array(1=>'first year',2=>'second year',3=>'third year',4=>'fourth year',5=>'fifth year'),
   '#required' => true,
   '#default_value'=>array(1,0,0,0,0),
   );
```

The problem:
I intended the first option to be selected but this is what am getting
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A radio group can only have one radio selected. Did you try '1' as default value?

Comment: damn, you wont believe how long i have been trying to fix this :)

Comment: yes, sunday was made to sleep. Might be a good reason for that

Answer (score 3):

The working code to use:

```
$form['yearofstudy']= array(
  '#title'   => t('What is your year of study'),
  '#type'    => 'radios',
  '#options' => array(
     1 => t('first year'),
     2 => t('second year'),
     3 => t('third year'),
     4 => t('fourth year'),
     5 => t('fifth year')
  ),
  '#required'      => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => 1
);
```

p.s. also, according to drupal rules, we must use [function t](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/8) as in code above.

Answer (score 1):

The definitive solution is here:

http://www.molecularsciences.org/drupal/making_your_checkboxes_preselected_in_edit_forms

The gist is to pass into #options an array of (name => name, name => name... ) and then the #default_value an array of (tid => name, tid => name...) for only the selected options and this gives us pre-selected options.